# How to set ngModel's $viewValue of an input immediately despite debounce being set

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

Suppose, I want to apply a masking function to a text input. It could be to properly stylize the phone number input (for example, for input `5553334444`, it would output `(555) 333-4444`), or just simply to uppercase the value in the input control.

The approach that I know uses `ngModel` controller (via `require: "ngModel"`) and sets the new uppercased `$viewValue` in the `$parser` function:

```
ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(val){
  var uppercase = val && val.toUpperCase();
  if (uppercase !== val){
    ngModel.$setViewValue(uppercase);
    ngModel.$render();
  }
  return uppercase;
});
```

But now, suppose, I would like to use `ng-model-options="{debounce: 400}"` because I don't want to trigger a change in the model too rapidly:

```
<input ng-model="foo" ng-model-options="{debounce: 400}"
       ng-change="doBackendQuery(foo)"
       uppercase>
```

In the example above, I don't want to trigger `doBackendQuery` too rapidly because it makes an HTTP call. `debounce` would prevent that from happening, but it would also prevent the `uppercase` directive from executing immediately, leading to users seeing lowercase text.

**Q**: how can I write `uppercase` directive to change the `$viewValue` immediately, and without waiting for `debounce`?

(Note: I do NOT want to make assumptions about the underlying DOM element - this would go against the idea of DOM-agnostic `ng-model`)

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/c50PEtbUVw3E9M2KG4at?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

A hacky solution (untested):

```
<input ng-model="foo" ng-model-options="{debounce: 400}"
   ng-change="doBackendQuery(foo)"
   uppercase style="text-transform: uppercase;">
```

You could also potentially change your `uppercase` directive to set that style automatically, or use css:

```
input[uppercase] {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joel. I mentioned `uppercase` here purely as an illustrative example. The question is broader than this.

Comment: Cool - I thought that may have been the case (hence considering this a hacky solution). I'm not sure of a 'real' way to tackle the broader problem at this point though. Best of luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
app.directive('capitalize', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            element.on('input', function() {
                var capitalized = element.val().toUpperCase();
                element.val(capitalized);
                modelCtrl.$setViewValue(capitalized);
            });

            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                return value.toUpperCase();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function(){

    angular
        .module('example', [])
        .directive('uppercase', [function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs, ngModel){

                    iElem.on('input', function(){
                        var elem = angular.element(this),
                            valOrigin = elem.val();
                        
                        val = toUpperCase(valOrigin);

                        elem.val( val );

                        ngModel.$viewValue = toLowerCase(valOrigin);
                    });

                    ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value){
                        value = toLowerCase(value);

                        return value;
                    });

                    ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value){
                        value = toUpperCase(value);

                        return value;
                    });

                    function toLowerCase(value){
                        return (value + '').toLowerCase();
                    }

                    function toUpperCase(value){
                        return (value + '').toUpperCase();
                    }

                }
            }
        }])
        .controller('ExampleController', [function() {
            
            var vc = this;

            vc.user = {
                name: 'let\' start!'
            };

        }]);

    angular
        .bootstrap(document, ['example']);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="ExampleController as example">
  <form name="userForm">

    <label>Name:
      <input type="text" name="userName" uppercase ng-model="example.user.name" ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}" />
    </label>

    <p>Name: <span>{{ example.user.name }}</span></p>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Add some description about what you have changed.

Comment: Thanks, but your solution makes an assumption about the underlying DOM element - i.e. that it is an `<input>` tag. This defeats the purpose of using the `ngModel` framework. I stated in the question that the solution should not make any assumptions about the DOM.